# No url is working after shifting magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I have shifted my magento 1.9 installation from `<domain>/shop` to `<domain>`. Front page of my magento loads fine, but none of the link thereafter does not work whatsoever. All of them throws 404 error. All the category pages, products page, admin page, CMS pages throws 404 error.

I followed database approach from link
http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/magento/how-to-change-url

Please help.

To add more info, I have updated table `core_config_data`, rows with path 'web/unsecure/base_url' and 'web/secure/base_url'. After that, I have cleaned cache, but to no avail.

Then, I tried changing admin url by editing `app/var/local.xml`, but that also didn't work.

Comment: what is the url for your site?

Comment: it's www.manihaar.com

Comment: Have you removed all folders under /var/cache

Comment: Yes @Bobadevv, I had removed all folders under /var. However, I resolved the problem by some more R&D. Thank you very much for your help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. While copying the files from sub-domain to primary domain, I didn't copy `.htaccess` file. Copying this file solved the problem.